# Is the set of discrete measures measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ be a measurable space.

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P),(\Omega',\mathscr{F}',P')$ be probability spaces and $G:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^\mathfrak{M}, \otimes_{A\in \mathfrak{M}} \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ be a measurable function and $H:(\Omega',\mathscr{F}')\rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^\mathfrak{M}, \otimes_{A\in \mathfrak{M}} \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}})$ be a measurable function.

Suppose that $G_*P=H_*P'$ and $G(x),H(y)$ are probability measures on $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ for every $x,y$.

If we know that $G(x)$ is a discrete measure for almost every $x$, can we conclude that $H(x)$ is a discrete measure?

Comment: I guess it's a valid question, but $\otimes_{A\in \mathfrak{M}} \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is almost certainly not the $\sigma$-algebra you really want to consider on the space of measures.  It is way too small.  Can you give some indication of the motivation behind this question?

Comment: @NateEldredge It can be shown that there exists a Dirichlet process $G$ (as the domain and range given above in the question) whose marginals are discrete. If $H$ is another Dirichlet process (as the domain and range given above in the question), then it can be also shown that $G=H$ in distribution. I want to conclude that marginals of $H$ is also discrete. (Hence, we can finally conclude that "every Dirichlet process has a discrete marginals")