# Are these two measurable maps equal in distribution?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Related : [Is the set of discrete measures measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3438129/44669)

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ be a measurable space and $Prob(X,\mathfrak{M})$ be the set of probability measures on $(X,\mathfrak{M})$.

Define $A_{t,B}:=\{\mu\in Prob(X,\mathfrak{M}): \mu(B)\leq t\}$ for each $t\in [0,\infty]$ and $B\in \mathfrak{M}$.

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be collection of all such $A_{t,B}$ and $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$ the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr{C}$.

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space and $G,H:(\Omega,\mathscr{F})\rightarrow (Prob(X,\mathfrak{M}),\mathscr{C})$ be measurable functions.

My question is the following:

1. If $G_*P=H_*P$ and $G_x$ is discrete almost everywhere, then is $H_x$ discrete almost everywhere too?
2. Let $D$ be the set of discrete measures on $(X,\mathfrak{M})$. Then, is $D\in \sigma(\mathscr{C})$?

If $2$ is true, then this implies that $1$ is true. But I don't know how to prove $D$ is measurable in this case.. How do I prove $1$?

(Note that in my past post, I tried to show that $D$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$ algebra, but as written in the comment there, I realized that this $\sigma$ algebra is too small! So I tried to enlarge the $\sigma$-algebra on $P(X,\mathfrak{M})$ in this post.. I think this direction is correct. If $D$ is not even measurable with respect to $\sigma(\mathscr{C})$, how much should we enlarge the sigma-algebra to make $D$ measurable..?)